# Вывести член класса в Binding

Tags: c#, .net, binding

Требуется создать источник данных для ComboBox. В качестве ItemsSource для него установлен экземпляр следующего класса (незначимые поля опущены):

```
public class TemperatureDimension : IDimension, IEnumerable
{
    private List<IUnit> _Units;

    public List<IUnit> Units
    {
        get
        {
            return _Units;
        }
    }
    public TemperatureDimension()
    {
        _Units =new List<IUnit>{
            new Celsius(),
            new Kelvin(),
            new Farenheit()
        };
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _Units.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

В принципе, логично, что этот код не работает и ComboBox не заполняется данными. Я вижу следующие решения этой задачи:

1) Написать что-нибудь в роде

```
<ComboBox Width="100" Height="30" ItemsSource="{Binding Dimension.Units}" />
```

2) Исправить код так, чтобы класс являлся коллекцией, содержащей Items. Я попытался решить эту задачу, реализовав интерфейс IEnumerable, возвращая в методе GetEnumerator нумератор списка. Но безрезультатно.

Есть идеи?

UPD. Пытался также реализовывать интерфейс IEnumerable<T>. В этом случае не компилируется.

Comment: Стоило бы указать теги вроде .Net, C#...

Comment: Попробуйте не `IEnumerable`, а `IEnumerable<IUnit>`. Что именно не компилируется в этом случае?

Comment: А какая проблема с `{Binding Dimension.Units}`? Вроде всё правильно. Что пишет в лог (окно Output) про ошибки Binding?

Comment: @VladD, при попытке реализовать интерфейс IEnumerable <IUnit> пишу:
        
    public IEnumerator<IUnit> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _Units.GetEnumerator();
    }

не компилируется. Такая ошибка:

Calc.MeasuringSystem.TemperatureDimension не реализует член интерфейса "System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()". "Calc.MeasuringSystem.TemperatureDimension.GetEnumerator()" не удается реализовать "System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()", поскольку он не содержит соответствующего типа возвращаемого значения "System.Collections.IEnumerator".

Как правильно сделать?

Comment: @VladD, при {Binding Dimension.Units} ComboBox не заполняется данными. Ресурс 100% существует (наблюдал его в отладчике). В отладчике также заметил, что не вызывается метод get поля Units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня всё работает (ц).

Наверное, вы

1. Не объявили Dimension как property, а только как поле?
2. Реализовывая `IEnumerable<IUnit>`, забыли про один из методов `GetEnumerator()` (их должно быть два!).

Вот как нужно имплементировать `IEnumerable<IUnit>`:

```
class TemperatureDimension : IEnumerable<IUnit>
{
    private List<IUnit> _Units;

    public List<IUnit> Units { get { return _Units; } }

    public TemperatureDimension()
    {
        _Units = new List<IUnit> { new Celsius(), new Kelvin(), new Fahrenheit() };
    }

    public IEnumerator<IUnit> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _Units.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

---

Кто-нибудь знает, как прикрепить архив?

---

Вот вам архив в текстовом виде :-) http://pastebin.com/xUwaKxAT

Запускаете программу (не забудьте поменять путь в Main на тот, который вам подходит!), получаете архив, распаковываете его, получаете Solution, в котором оба метода с комбобоксами работают. Вот.

Comment: Простите, что зря вас побеспокоил. Вы правы: привязка работает и при реализации интерфейса IEnumerable<IUnit>, и при явном указании свойства в Xaml. У меня, как оказалось, ошибка была в другом: из-за недостаточно отлаженной сериализации при создании объекта создаётся экземпляр класса TemperatureDimension, но после сериализации он сбрасывается в Null. Поэтому теперь проблема решена.

Comment: @Alouette: главное — что проблема решена! Рад был помочь. Даже если это и не понадобилось, возможно, ответ подтолкнул вас к поискам в правильном месте.